# CPYTOIMPF does not work on a table which contains CLOB data

Tags: ibm-midrange

I need to copy a table which contains CLOB data to IFS. When I use CPYTOIMPF, It gives me a error saying that'To-File not allowed'. CPYTOIMPF is as below"

{

```
CPYTOIMPF FROMFILE(*LIBL/SYSLINKF) TOSTMF('/DIG_WRE/test1') MBROPT(*REPL
ACE) STMFCCSID(*PCASCII) RCDDLM(*CRLF) DTAFMT(*DLM) STRDLM(*NONE) FLDDLM('
,')
```

}

IS there a way to do this. THe same command works with a table without CLOB data. The field which contains CLOB data is XML.

Answer (score 1):

/* Disclaimer un-tested but what I would try first I'm only just experimenting with CLOB fields and nosql */

**Export a file with CLOB from db2 using cpytoimpf**

1. Create a view which casts the clob field to varchar(32000)
2. cpytoimpf from the view.